# 'The default schema does not exist' on deploy of SQL CLR assembly onto SQL Server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I'm deploying an example `SQL CLR` stored procedure which has a `SQL CLR` type as parameter using Visual Studio 2008 and menu `Project -> Deploy`.

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void TakeTariff(TariffInfo tariffInfo) { }
}

public class TariffInfo
{
    public SqlDecimal Amount { get; private set; }
}
```

but getting next strange error:

```
The default schema does not exist.
```

How can I fix that?

My user was created this way:

```
CREATE USER myUser FOR LOGIN myLogin_mod WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = mySchema
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? When you run CREATE ASSEMBLY?

Comment: @Ashish Gupta: Using Visual Studio 2008 and menu Project -> Deploy

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to run this to create the schema *before* you add objects to it...

```
CREATE SCHEMA mySchema AUTHORIZATION myUser --or dbo
```

[`CREATE USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) does not check this:

> ...DEFAULT_SCHEMA can be set to a schema that does not currently exist in the database...